# Dto map and use-case

Tags: android, kotlin, dto, use-case

how can I make Dto map and pass it to the use-case using clean architecture in android kotlin

i tried to make an object class and pass it to the use-case but it didn't work

Comment: This question needs some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I will use **HILT** for dependency injection ... you can use any di library.

You can make a base interface mapper for objects like this:

```
interface mapper <T,R> {
   fun map(t: T): R
}
```

Then create a class that implements **Mapper** interface:

```
class ProductMapper @Inject constructor() : Mapper<RemoteProduct, ProductModel>() {

     override fun map(t: RemoteProduct): ProductModel {
         // Pass any argument you want or do some business logic
         return ProductModel(t.id, t.name)
     }
```

Now I Suggest injecting this **ProductMapper** inside the repo when you get the response from API or locale database then return mapped data to the use-case.

But anyway you can inject this mapper inside use-case like this:

```
class GetProductsUseCase @Inject constructor (private val productsMapper: ProductsMapper) {

   // Don't forget to inject your repo too
   operator fun invoke(): ProductMode {
       return productsMapper.map(repo.getProduct())
   }

}
```

Finally using **Hilt** create new module to bind **ProductMapper** in our case there is no need to do that step but if your mapper depends on another classes you need to add it in module like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingltonComponent::Class)
interface AppModule {
   
  @Binds
  fun bindProductDetailsMapper(productsMapper: ProductsMapper): Mapper

}
```